# Yii2 translation is not working for spanish but is working for other languages

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Yii2 app with four languages:

- English
- Spanish
- French
- Portuguese

I have implemented the language switcher and translated all the messages files generated by the following command:

```
php yii message/extract @app/config/i18n.php
```

Here are the configurations I use for i18n and the language switcher

**config/web.php**

```
'bootstrap' => ['log','languageSwitcher'],
'language'=> 'en', // spanish
'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        'app' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'basePath' => '@app/messages',
            'forceTranslation' => true,
        ],
        'kvgrid' => [
             'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
             'basePath' => '@app/messages',
             'forceTranslation' => true,
        ],
    ],
],
'languageSwitcher' => [
     'class' => 'app\widgets\languageSwitcher',
],
```

**config/i18n.php**

```
return [
    'sourcePath' => __DIR__. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'..',
    'messagePath' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'..'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'messages',
    'languages' => ['en','fr','es','po'],
    'translator' => 'Yii::t',
    'sort' => false,
    'overwrite' => true,
    'removeUnused' => false,
    'markUnused' => true,
    'except' => [
        '.svn',
        '.git',
        '.gitignore',
        '.gitkeep',
        '.hgignore',
        '.hgkeep',
        '/messages',
        '/BaseYii.php',
        '/vendor',
    ],
    'only' => [
        '*.php',
    ],
    'format' => 'php',
    'db' => 'db',
    'sourceMessageTable' => '{{%source_message}}',
    'messageTable' => '{{%message}}',
    'catalog' => 'messages',
    'ignoreCategories' => [],
];
```

**widgets/languageSwitcher.php**

```
<?php
namespace app\widgets;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\bootstrap\ButtonDropdown;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\web\Cookie;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class languageSwitcher extends Widget
{
    public $languages = [
        'en' => 'English',
        'fr' => 'Français',
        'es' => 'Español',
        'po' => 'Português',
    ];
    public function init()
    {
        if(php_sapi_name() === 'cli')
        {
            return true;
        }
        parent::init();
        $languageNew = Yii::$app->request->get('language');
        if($languageNew)
        {
            {
                Yii::$app->language = $languageNew;
                Yii::$app->session->set('language', $languageNew);
            }
        }
        elseif(Yii::$app->session->get('language'))
        {
            Yii::$app->language = Yii::$app->session->get('language');
        }
        else
        {
            Yii::$app->language = 'en';
        }
    }

    public static function getFlag(){
        $current = Yii::$app->language; //$languages[Yii::$app->language];
        return "<img src='/img/flags/".Yii::$app->language.".png' style='height:20px;'>";
    }

    public function run(){
        $languages = $this->languages;
        $current = $languages[Yii::$app->language];
        ?>
            <div>
            <?php foreach ($languages as $code => $language): ?>
                <?php $cl = "btn-".$code;
                $img = "<img src='/img/flags/".$code.".png' style='height:20px;'> ".t($language); ?>
                <div class='<?php echo $cl; ?>'>
                    <?= Html::a($img, Url::current(['language' => $code]));?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

**@app/messages**

[image: structure of message folder]

The current issue is the fact that when I use the language switcher to switch between languages, every language works except Spanish. I see translations for English, French, Portuguese but when it comes to Spanish the modules using:

```
Yii:t('app', 'my text');
```

Are not translated. However the default yii2 test is as the `(not set)` in gridviews are translated to `(no definido)`.

- I have tried changing `es` to `es-ES` and regenerating the messages and this was without success.
- I have tried to use the french translation in the spanish file and it doesn't show either.
- I have tried using the spanish translation in the french translation file and this shows translations when I choose french.
- I have tried removing the `forceTranslation`

Why does the translation not work for spanish but works for other languages?

Comment: Really weird... Could you provide code for `languageSwitcher` and structure of your files in `@app/messages` folder?

Comment: @Bizley I have added the code as well as an image of the structure

Comment: I don't know what is the reason why only `es` is not working here. You are obviously adding `languageSwitcher` to bootstrap phase even though it is not implementing `BootstrapInterface` but this is rather not a problem here since other languages work... I recommend reading Samdark's [Yii 2 Cookbook](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/i18n-selecting-application-language.md) with language selection for inspiration.

Comment: @Bizley Yeah I do feel the fact that it only does this for `es` to be pretty weird. I have read Samdark's cookbook this is were I got the impression that changing `es` to `es-ES` could make a difference but for some reason it didn't .